# Arraylist of objects empty?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

so in this class for the choice == 1, it does not go into the for loop through the ArrayList of objects, does it mean the object is empty? because i declared objects at the beginning and added them to the ArrayList store.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Team> store = new ArrayList<>();
        Random gener = new Random();
        String tourName , tourDate , location;
        int maxNumberofTeams , avalSoft, avalHard , avalFieldTest;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter tournament Name?\n");
        tourName = input.next();
        System.out.print("please Enter tournament Date\n");
        tourDate = input.next();
        System.out.print("please Enter location\n");
        location = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Max number of Teams\n");
        maxNumberofTeams = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter avalSoft\n");
        avalSoft = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter aval Hard\n");
        avalHard = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter avalFieldTest\n");
        avalFieldTest = input.nextInt();
        Tournament tour = new Tournament (tourName , tourDate, location , maxNumberofTeams, avalSoft , avalHard, avalFieldTest);
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= maxNumberofTeams ; i++)
        {
            String teamName , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor , judgeLocation;
            int teamNumber , noOfTeamMem , robotId;
            System.out.print("Please Enter %s team Name\n");
            teamName = input.next();
            System.out.print("Number of Team Memebers\n");
            noOfTeamMem = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please Enter Sponsoring Schoolr\n");
            sponsoringSchool = input.next();
            System.out.print("Please Enter financialSponsor\n");
            financialSponsor = input.next();
            System.out.print("Please Enter judge Location\n");
            judgeLocation = input.next();
            teamNumber = i;
            System.out.print("Please Enter an ID for robot\n");
            robotId = input.nextInt();
            Robot robbb = new Robot();
            Team team = new Team(teamName , teamNumber , noOfTeamMem , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor, judgeLocation, robbb);
            Robot rob = new Robot (team , robbb);
            store.add(team);
        }
        int choice=0;
        while(choice >= 0)
          {
            System.out.print("MENU\n"
                    + "1)PREPARING TEAM TURN ROBOT ON\n"
                    +"2)PREPARING TEAM HARDWARE\n"
                    + "3)HAVE HW INSPECT READY ROBOT\n"
                    + "4)HAVE PRERPARING TEAM TAKE HW_INSPECTED ROBOT TO STATION\n"
                    + "5)HAVE SW INSPECT ROBOT\n"
                    + "6)HAVE A PREPARING TEAM TAKE TO FIELD TEST\n"
                    + "7)HAVE A FIELD TEST INSPEC\n"
                    + "8)HAVE A BEFORE TEAM GO TO JUDGE\n"
                    + "9)HAVE JUDGES INTERVIEW\n"
                    + "10)CHANGE TEAM STATUS TO PASSED_INSPECTION\n"
                    + "11)TOURNAMENT STATUS TO MATCH\n"
                    + "12)\n"
                    + "13)ROBOT CAN'T PLAY IF OFF, READY, OR STILL AT TESTING\n"
                    + "14)CHANGE TOURNAMENT TO MATCHES\n"
                    + "15)GENERATE POINTS\n"
                    + "16)JUDGE POINTS\n"
                    + "17)CHANGE TOURNAMENT TO AWARDS\n"
                    + "18)PRINT TOP TEAMS JUDGING\n"
                    + "19) PRINT TOP BY QULIFYING \n"
                    + "20)DISPLAY TEAM PERSONS\n"
                    + "21)DISPLAY TEAM INFO\n"
                    + "22)DISPLAY INFO ABOUT ROBOTS\n"
                    + "23)INFO ABOUT TOURNAMENT\n"
                    + "24)END\n");

            choice = input.nextInt();
            Team temp = new Team();
            Robot robottemp = new Robot();
            Tournament tourr = new Tournament();
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("Phase"+choice);
                for (int i = 0 ; i >= store.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Phase"+choice);
                    store.get(i).teamStatus = temp.teamStatus.PREPARING;
                    if (store.get(i).teamStatuss == 1)
                    {
                     store.get(i).robot.robotStatusChoice(1);
                     System.out.print("PHASE 1 COMPLETED\n");
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the robot class in which i called the method;

```
public int teamNumber;
    public int robotId;
    public Robot robot;
    Random gener = new Random();
    public int robotStatusChoice;
    ArrayList stations = new ArrayList();
    public int Height;
    public int Width = 22;
    public int Depth;
    public Team TeamAssigned = new Team("TEAMNAME", 1 , 1, "SS", "FS", "JL",robot);
    public robotStatus robotStatus;

    public Robot()
    {

    }
    public Robot( Team TeamAssigned ,Robot  robot){
        this.robot = robot;
        this.TeamAssigned = TeamAssigned;
    }


public void robotStatusChoice(int i) {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                this.robotStatusChoice = i;
                this.robotStatus = robotStatus.READY;
            }
            else if( i == 2)
            {
                this.robotStatusChoice = i;
                this.robotStatus = robotStatus.HW_INSP_PASSED;
            }
            else if ( i == 3)
            {
                this.robotStatusChoice = i;
                this.robotStatus = robotStatus.FIELD_TEST_PASSED;
            }
            else if ( i > 3 || i < 1)
            {
                this.robotStatusChoice = i;
                this.robotStatus = robotStatus.READY;
            }
        }
```

TeamSTatus Change ;

```
public void TeamStatus(int x)
    {
        if( x == 1 )
        {
            this.teamStatuss = x;
            this.teamStatus = teamStatus.PREPARING;
        }
        else if ( x == 2)
        {
            this.teamStatuss = x;
            this.teamStatus = teamStatus.PASSED_INSPECTION;
        }
        else if ( x == 3 )
        {
            this.teamStatuss = x;
            this.teamStatus = teamStatus.PLAYED5_MATCHES;
        }
        else if ( x == 4)
        {
            this.teamStatuss = x;
            this.teamStatus = teamStatus.INELIGIBLE;
        }
        else if ( x > 4 || x<1)
        {
            this.teamStatuss = x;
            this.teamStatus = teamStatus.INELIGIBLE;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please post a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect very little of the code you've posted is relevant - but it's also incomplete.

Comment: Can you post all the code that modifies `Team.teamStatus`?

Comment: @Ankosh is there an `enum teamStatus`? Also note that method names should start with a lower case [a-z]. Change the method name from `TeamStatus` to `setTeamStatus`, and change `store.get(i).teamStatus = temp.teamStatus.PREPARING` to `store.get(i).setTeamStatus(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `choice == 1` block at the end, you have your `for` loop condition backwards.  The next iteration of a `for` loop takes place when the condition is `true`, not `false`.  Reverse your condition.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < store.size(); i++)
```

Comment: i did that but it gave me "Java.lang.NullPointerException" error ? @rgettman

Comment: @Ankosh It looks like you've uncovered another bug in your program.  Please examine your stack trace to determine on what line the NPE is occurring.  That will tell you what object is null on which you're attempting to call a method.  Without knowing that line, we can only guess.

Comment: i updated the post and added the method that was used from the Robot class. @rgettman

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i >= store.size(); i++)
```

Unless `store` is empty (in which case you'll get an exception), `i >= store.size()` will immediately be `false`. You meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < store.size(); i++)
```

Or better yet, use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (Team team : store) {
    team.teamStatus = temp.teamStatus.PREPARING;
    if (team.teamStatuss == 1) {
        team.robot.robotStatusChoice(1);
        System.out.print("PHASE 1 COMPLETED\n");
    }
}
```

(Do you really have both `teamStatus` and `teamStatuss` as fields? That doesn't sound like a good idea to me.)

Comment: i did that but it gave me "Java.lang.NullPointerException" error ? @JonSkeet

Comment: @Ankosh: Then that's another problem you need to fix. I suggest you read http://tinyurl.com/so-npe and work on fixing it, asking another question (with only relevant code) *only* after trying hard to fix it yourself. Stack Overflow is not designed for a single question to end up being a sort of slow-motion interactive debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i >= store.size(); i++)
```

This might be a typo as you probably mean `i < store.size()`.

In your code you have:

```
Robot robbb = new Robot();
Team team = new Team(teamName , teamNumber , noOfTeamMem , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor, judgeLocation, robbb);
Robot rob = new Robot (team , robbb);
```

Now, you are passing an not properly instantiated `Robot()` (`robbb`) to the constructor of `Team`. Create a `setRobot(Robot robot)` method to update the `Team`'s robot to `rob`, which is a `Robot` with references to the `Team` before adding the `Team` to the `List`.

```
public void setRobot(Robot rob) { this.robot = rob; };
```

Comment: i did that but it gave me "Java.lang.NullPointerException" error ? @M. Shaw

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and update the code in your post?

Comment: Can you post the constructors of `Robot`?

Comment: update also. @M. Shaw

Comment: don't see anything......... ? @M. Shaw

Comment: Added the method in team.